# why are overloaded private shared function not accessible when called from shared function in same class

Tags: vb.net

Came across something I found interesting and would love an explanation.

*Edit*

*This question is not meant to be answered with what should be done to fix it. I know the fixes. I want an explanation of why the compiler does what it does. Ex. Are the private functions not considered given this scenario?*

**Problem**

I have a class that has a public shared(static) function called WhatIs. WhatIs takes a parameter that has a collection of objects. the code iterates over this collection and calls a WhatIs function that has a parameter matching type of what the object is.

When executed, an InvalidCastException exception is thrown because the execution is trying to call the WhatIs function that started this, not the one for the type provided.

That's weird, but what made it odd to me was when you change the private shared functions to public shared then it works fine.

Even odder, when you explicit cast the object then it works even if the function is private.

What?! someone please explain

**Code**

*the guts:*

```
Public Class House
    Public Property Furniture As ICollection(Of Object)

    Public Sub New()
        Furniture = New List(Of Object)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Chair
    Public Property IsComfortable As Boolean
End Class

Public Class Table
    Public Seats As Integer
End Class

Public Class HouseExaminer
    Public Shared Function WhatIs(thing As House) As String
        Dim isA As String = "a house that contains "

        For Each item In thing.Furniture
            isA &= WhatIs(item)
        Next

        Return isA
    End Function

    Private Shared Function WhatIs(thing As Chair) As String
        Return "a " & If(thing.IsComfortable, "comfortable", "uncomfortable") & " chair "
    End Function

    Private Shared Function WhatIs(thing As Table) As String
        Return "a table that seats " & thing.Seats & " iguanas"
    End Function
End Class
```

*to test*

```
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting
Imports stuff

<TestClass()>
Public Class HouseExaminerTests

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub TestWhatIs()
        Dim given As New House()
        Dim expected As String
        Dim actual As String

        given.Furniture.Add(New Chair() With {.IsComfortable = True})
        given.Furniture.Add(New Table() With {.Seats = 4})

        expected = "a house that contains a comfortable chair a table that seats 4 iguanas"
        actual = HouseExaminer.WhatIs(given)

        Assert.Equals(expected, actual)
    End Sub
End Class
```

*result*

debug the test and you get this:
InvalidCastException
Method invocation failed because 'Public Shared Function WhatIs(thing As stuff.House) As String' cannot be called with these arguments:

Argument matching parameter 'thing' cannot convert from 'Chair' to 'House'.

**These changes make it work but why?!**

*make em public*

change the private shared functions in HouseExaminer to public, rerun test. spoiler, it works

*explicitly cast the objects*

change them back to private then replace

```
isA &= WhatIs(item)
```

with

```
If TypeOf item Is Chair Then isA &= WhatIs(CType(item, Chair))
If TypeOf item Is Table Then isA &= WhatIs(CType(item, Table))
```

rerun test, and what do u know, it works

Comment: Add Option Strict On, and then define an Interface which is supported by all furniture, e.g. iFurniture, and it requires the objects to define a String returning function.

Comment: see comments in response to w.brian's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, it looks like you have implicit conversions turned on.  That is the start of the issue.  Secondly, you define `Furniture` as a `List(of Object)`.  Your first call to `WhatIs` is succeeding.  The compiler is making a best guess as to which overload to use when passing what *it* sees as simply `Object` as it iterates through `thing.Furniture`, and it determines the public static version of the `WhatIs` method to be the most appropriate.  It then attempts to implicitly convert `Object` to `House`, and inevitably fails.

Why does casting work?  Because it takes the guess work out of determining which overload to use.

Moral of the story is: Don't make the compiler guess.  Implicit conversion can lead to tricky bugs.

**Edit**:  *Why doesn't the compiler see the other overloaded functions?*

The compiler has to determine the correct overload to use at *compile time*.  It does not wait until runtime to determine which overload to use, and therefore doesn't have the luxury of inspecting the type of the object to determine the most appropriate overload.

Since the compiler only knows that `furniture` is a `List(Of Object)`, technically (with implicit conversion turned on) all three of the overloads are deemed "appropriate," but the compiler must choose one.  It ranks the possible overload candidates, and chooses the `public` version ahead of the `private` ones.

Comment: the List(of object) is done on purpose. that's where the real goofy comes from. normally I would be more specific, but this came up in real world due to XSD generated classes so it might be something others would run into.

Comment: and I should add, I know there are easy fixes, like interaces / abstract classes. this was meant more for, why does the compiler act the way it does in this scenario

Comment: +1 just for morale of the story. but I want to hold out for geek answer to why the compiler doesn't see the privates in this scenario when implicit conversion is done.

Comment: It's a combination of overload resolution + implicit conversion.  The compiler only knows as much information as you give it, and all it knows is that `Furniture` is a collection of `Object`.  The compiler says, "What is the most appropriate overload to use?" and determines that the public static version is the most appropriate, and then it attempts to convert `Object` to `House`.  If you had implicit conversion turned off, this code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I know, but WHY does the compiler not see the private functions in this case. totally agree on best practice so you don't need to explain it ;)

Comment: It *does* see the other two.  The compiler has to determine which of the overloads is the most appropriate, and given the amount of information you've made available to the compiler, it determines that the `public` one is the most appropriate.  The compiler ranks public methods ahead of lesser-scoped methods when all else is equal.

Comment: except, not all else is equal. watch item and debug on the line. it knows its a chair. but when it runs the answer is different than the watch. that's what is wrong to me.

Comment: I've updated my answer.  The compiler determines the overload at compile time, not run time.  It doesn't matter that at runtime the debugger knows it's a chair, by that point, the overload that must be used has already been determined.

Comment: Watch and debug are showing what is known at *run-time* based on the actual object instances.  Overload resolution is performed at compile-time based on the types of the parameters.  In this case, the type of parameter is `Object`, so the public method that takes a house is determined to be the best one merely because it is public.

Comment: w.brian - your last sentence of last comment + steven's clears it up for me. I don't like the answer (simply cause its public, GRRRR stupid compiler!) but accept this explains it :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use **always**

   Option Strict On
2. You cannot make it more flexible by adding Methods equal in name, just with different parametertypes.

**Update**

```
Private Function ShowMe(data As Integer) As String
    Return data.ToString
End Function

Private Function ShowMe(data As String) As String
    Return data
End Function

Private Function ShowMe(data As Double) As String
    Return data.ToString
End Function

Dim bla As New List(Of Object)
```

if you then call

```
    bla.Add(12)
    bla.Add("hi")
    bla.Add(1.2)
    Dim text As String
    text = ShowMe(bla(0))
    text = ShowMe(bla(1))
    text = ShowMe(bla(2))
```

then the compiler will always complain that the correct method does not exist, because the correct method is not selected by checking the type, instead it is selected by the definition, for which type the container is defined for.

```
Private Function ShowMe(data As Object) As String
    Return data.ToString
End Function
```

this would be called for all integer, doubles and strings. If it is not available, then some methods are used that can do some kind of automatic conversion. Thats why you can put an integer in a float, or put a number in a string.

One way would be to check for its type and do an explizit type conversion

```
    For Each ele As Object In bla
        If TypeOf ele Is Integer Then
            text = ShowMe(CInt(ele))
        ElseIf TypeOf ele Is Double Then
            text = ShowMe(CDbl(ele))
        Else
            text = ShowMe(CStr(ele))
        End If
    Next
```

But this is still not so clean. If you want to access properties that all objects should support, then put them in a container and define the type as something that assures that those properties exist.

Comment: on pt 1, agreed. this was done for theory purposes. on pt 2, there's nothing wrong with equal names, different params, in fact that's what overloading is so not sure I get you're point

Comment: It is nothing wrong with overloading, but the thing that _unfortunately_ does not work, is the correct selection of the fitting overloaded method by checking the real type of the given parameters. See update in answer

Comment: I follow you. interesting point. since all functions are private then none would be used. HA! doesn't even rank according to pub/private just ignores privates on implicit conversion. thanks for putting together a though out answer. not exactly what I was looking for, but +1 cause you brought in good supplemental